# ElementTree / Python - How to insert single tag in a node?

Tags: python, elementtree

everyone

This works, but result is:

```
new = ET.Element("tagname")
new.text = "data"
i.insert(0,new)
```

Result:

```
<tagname></tagname>
```

I want

```
<tagname/>
```

Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Are you using the xml module from the standard library, or lxml ?

Comment: ........First..

Comment: Could you please post a complete code, that can be run ? We can't see where 'i' is coming from, nor how you are obtaining the result (tostring ? write ?)

Comment: Thank you, it seems I've found - SubElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a SubElement      :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement